# Show Disable Previous Next Pagination Nav

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, genesis

I am using eleven 40 Pro theme. I want to show disable "Previous" pagination on 1st page and “Next” button on the last page.

As for example if I am on the homepage it only show the next button to click.

Can somebody help me please? Appreciated for you kind help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $page_no = $_GET['page_no']; ?>
<button <?php echo $page_no==1? 'disabled':'' ?> > Previous </button> 
<button <?php echo $page_no==40? 'disabled':'' ?> > Next </button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I tried the above code on snippet, doesn't work.

Comment: You have insert a get parameter in url for first page and last page, then you can put condition on this paramter value i.e `$page_no = $_GET['page_no']` **if $page_no==1** its mean it's your first page and put disabled attribute in previous button html; **if $page==40**  (confirm that its your last page) then also put disabled attribute in next button html.

Comment: You mean to add homepage page id?

Comment: yes you can consider page id as a page number if all pages have id and in sorting i.e page_id=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and so on...

Comment: `$page_no = $_GET['page_no']; ?>
<button <?php echo $page_no==0? 'disabled':'' ?> > Previous </button> 
<button <?php echo $page_no==40? 'disabled':'' ?> > Next </button>`

I tried this above code on snippet, it doesn't work on frontend.

Comment: please share your URL so i can assist you in details

Comment: Refer to url [staging](https://motivatelimit.s4-tastewp.com/)